# iOS image upload show's 404 error from server

Tags: php, ios, image, file-upload, nsurlconnection

I have done the image upload part before (NsurlConn, Synchrequest), but this time there is some strange things going on while uploading the image from simulator to a php server, as i am receiving the 404 page not found (as response i am receiving the whole html 404 page code :-) ), when i hit the url, using browser address bar it give me proper error message and not 404 page not found, have tried all possibilities , the same thing is working fine using rest-client, can you guys help me out of this, its get hard for me to find the actual issue, and the same webservices is getting called by android device which is working fine, an image is getting upload using android.

Thank guys!!!

Comment: Do you have any reserved characters (eg spaces, punctuation, non-ASCII) characters in the URL? Sometimes web browsers will seamlessly percent escape those for you, and you have to explicitly do this yourself when doing this programmatically.

Comment: Worst case scenario, request the page via your web browser while running [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Repeat this process, this time making the request from your app. Compare and contrast the requests.

Comment: @Rob No Such characters are present, a normal image uploading is there.even tried encoding url, no success yet

Comment: One thing to note here: the browser issues a GET request for that URL and your iOS code (probably) issues a POST request - depending on the server structure this could be routed to two different locations (hence the difference in responses).

Comment: @rokjarc it is working as post on rest-client (Post man), also working fine the same post using android device, also what i did, i change the post url to some another(server action) and the data(file, and parameters are visible over there)

Comment: You might want to add your iOS request creating code to your question then - otherwise all we can do is guess.